# How do I retrieve the value of php stdClass Object

Tags: php, object, stdclass

This is probably simple, but I am at my wits end.

I am using an API.  I declare $checkLead and get a stdClassObject that will be displayed below.  I am trying to retrieve a value of the array. In this instance there is one record, but it may include more in the future.

Here is what gets printed when I print_r.

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [result] => stdClass Object ( 
        [count] => 1 
        [leadRecordList] => stdClass Object ( 
            [leadRecord] => stdClass Object ( 
                [Id] => 26 
                [Email] => test3@test.com 
                [ForeignSysPersonId] => 
                [ForeignSysType] => 
                [leadAttributeList] => stdClass Object ( 
                    [attribute] => Array ( 
                        [0] => stdClass Object ( 
                            [attrName] => FirstName 
                            [attrType] => string 
                            [attrValue] => JJ 
                        )
                        [1] => stdClass Object ( 
                            [attrName] => LastName 
                            [attrType] => string 
                            [attrValue] => JJ 
                        ) 
                        [2] => stdClass Object ( 
                            [attrName] => Website 
                            [attrType] => url 
                            [attrValue] => test.com 
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Here is an example of a multiple result return.

```
stdClass Object (
[result] => stdClass Object (
    [count] => 2
    [leadRecordList] => stdClass Object (
        [leadRecord] => Array (
            [0] => stdClass Object (
                [Id] => 33
                [Email] => test3@test.com
                [ForeignSysPersonId] =>
                [ForeignSysType] =>
                [leadAttributeList] => stdClass Object (
                    [attribute] => Array (
                        [0] => stdClass Object (
                            [attrName] => FirstName
                            [attrType] => string
                            [attrValue] => jj )
                        [1] => stdClass Object (
                            [attrName] => LastName
                            [attrType] => string
                            [attrValue] => amonit )
                        [2] => stdClass Object (
                            [attrName] => Website
                            [attrType] => url
                            [attrValue] => test.com )
                        )
                    )
                )
            [1] => stdClass Object (
                [Id] => 26
                [Email] => test3@test.com
                [ForeignSysPersonId] =>
                [ForeignSysType] =>
                [leadAttributeList] => stdClass Object (
                    [attribute] => Array (
                        [0] => stdClass Object (
                            [attrName] => FirstName
                            [attrType] => string
                            [attrValue] => bob )
                        [1] => stdClass Object (
                            [attrName] => LastName
                            [attrType] => string
                            [attrValue] => smith )
                        [2] => stdClass Object (
                            [attrName] => Phone
                            [attrType] => phone
                            [attrValue] => 123-123-1234 )
                        [3] => stdClass Object (
                            [attrName] => Website
                            [attrType] => url
                            [attrValue] => test.com )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

So, I was wondering if someone could help me retrieve the value for `FirstName`.  I would also like to be able to retrieve the value by saying something like "what is the value of `LastName` where the `FirstName` is equal to `"JJ"`.

Comment: For `what is the value of LastName where the FirstName is equal to "JJ"` you would need to supply another example of when you had multiple records found. It looks like in this search you only got one result. If multiples were found there would be an array of results you would have to use foreach to go through to find the correct one.

Comment: Okay @Pitchinnate, I have got an example of a multiple result return.

I have added it to the OP.

 Thanks in advance for your help.  I am supposed to have a solution for this by Monday.

Comment: @Pitchinnate, regarding your response above.  I would like to know how to just retrieve values from either of those scenarios.  Please help me.  The solutions I have found on this and other sites just don't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a `foreach` to cycle through to find the correct value

```
$lastname = '';
foreach($checkLead->result->leadRecordList->leadRecord as $record) {
    $attributes = $record->leadAttributeList->attribute;
    $found = false;
    $temp_lastname = '';
    foreach($attributes as $attr) {
        if($attr->attrName == 'LastName') {
            $temp_lastname = $attr->attrValue;
        }
        if($attr->attrName == 'FirstName' && $attr->attrValue == 'JJ') {
            $found = true;
        }
    }
    if($found) {
        $lastname = $temp_lastname;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Pithcinnate Thank you for the response.  I placed that code in my file and when I tested it, it gave me this error 5x

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 28 

line 28 is the inner for each.  

other suggestions have given me this error.  Why doesn't PHP like this way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

To get the first name, you run the chance of getting multiple leads returned back to you from Marketo, or best case, a single lead. Here's the code for getting that information. Hope this helps.

```
if (is_object($checkLead)) {
    $leadRecord = $checkLead->result->leadRecordList->leadRecord;
    if (is_array($leadRecord)) {
        //multiple leads returned
        //run another foreach within a forloop to get the same values
        for($x=0; $x<sizeof($leadRecord); $x++) {
            $LeadAttribute = $leadRecord[$x]->leadAttributeList->attribute;
            foreach($LeadAttribute as $attribute) {
                if($attribute->attrName == 'FirstName') {
                    echo "\nFirst Name: ".$attribute->attrValue;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        //single lead returned
        $LeadAttribute = $leadRecord->leadAttributeList->attribute;
        foreach($LeadAttribute as $attribute) {
            if($attribute->attrName == 'FirstName') {
                echo "\nFirst Name: ".$attribute->attrValue;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the code below and it will work the way you expect it:

```
$lastname = '';

$leadRecord = $checkLead->result->leadRecordList->leadRecord;
if (  $checkLead->result->count > 1 ) {
    foreach ( $leadRecord as $leadRecordItem ) {
        foreach ( $leadRecordItem->leadAttributeList as $attributes ) {
            $found = false;
            $temp_lastname = '';
            foreach( $attributes as $attr ) {
                if($attr->attrName == 'LastName') {
                    $temp_lastname = $attr->attrValue;
                }
                if($attr->attrName == 'FirstName' && $attr->attrValue == 'JJ') {
                    $found = true;
                }
            }
            if($found) {
                $lastname = $temp_lastname;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
else {
    foreach ( $leadRecord->leadAttributeList as $attributes ) {
        $found = false;
        $temp_lastname = '';
        foreach( $attributes as $attr ) {
            if($attr->attrName == 'LastName') {
                $temp_lastname = $attr->attrValue;
            }
            if($attr->attrName == 'FirstName' && $attr->attrValue == 'JJ') {
                $found = true;
            }
        }
        if($found) {
            $lastname = $temp_lastname;
            break;
        }
    }
}

echo $lastname;
```

I built both your objects from scratch and tried this code, and at the end it echoed "JJ" - which I suppose is what you're after here, at least to get a grip on it and modify to your specific needs.

Just in case you want to try it out the way I did, here's how I built your single and multiple result return:

```
function to_object( $arr ) {
    return is_array( $arr ) ? (object) array_map(__FUNCTION__, $arr) : $arr;
}

$checkLeadArr2 = array(
    'result' => array(
        'count' => 2,
        'leadRecordList' => array(
            'leadRecord' => array(
                array(
                    'Id' => 33,
                    'Email' => 'test3@test.com',
                    'ForeignSysPersonId' => null,
                    'ForeignSysType' => null,
                    'leadAttributeList' => array(
                        'attribute' => array( 
                            array(
                                'attrName' => 'FirstName',
                                'attrType' => 'string',
                                'attrValue' => 'JJ',
                            ),
                            array(
                                'attrName' => 'LastName',
                                'attrType' => 'string',
                                'attrValue' => 'amonit',
                            ),
                            array(
                                'attrName' => 'Website',
                                'attrType' => 'url',
                                'attrValue' => 'test.com',
                            ),
                        )
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'Id' => 26,
                    'Email' => 'test3@test.com',
                    'ForeignSysPersonId' => null,
                    'ForeignSysType' => null,
                    'leadAttributeList' => array(
                        'attribute' => array( 
                            array(
                                'attrName' => 'FirstName',
                                'attrType' => 'string',
                                'attrValue' => 'JJ',
                            ),
                            array(
                                'attrName' => 'LastName',
                                'attrType' => 'string',
                                'attrValue' => 'JJ',
                            ),
                            array(
                                'attrName' => 'Website',
                                'attrType' => 'url',
                                'attrValue' => 'test.com',
                            ),
                        )
                    )
                ),
            )
        )
    )
);

$checkLeadArr1 = array(
    'result' => array(
        'count' => 1,
        'leadRecordList' => array(
            'leadRecord' => array(
                'Id' => 26,
                'Email' => 'test3@test.com',
                'ForeignSysPersonId' => null,
                'ForeignSysType' => null,
                'leadAttributeList' => array(
                    'attribute' => array( 
                        array(
                            'attrName' => 'FirstName',
                            'attrType' => 'string',
                            'attrValue' => 'JJ',
                        ),
                        array(
                            'attrName' => 'LastName',
                            'attrType' => 'string',
                            'attrValue' => 'JJ',
                        ),
                        array(
                            'attrName' => 'Website',
                            'attrType' => 'url',
                            'attrValue' => 'test.com',
                        ),
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);


$checkLead = to_object( $checkLeadArr1 );
```

You will just need to place this last code above the foreach loops I gave you before, and you can try the multiple result return by switching from `$checkLead = to_object( $checkLeadArr1 );` and `$checkLead = to_object( $checkLeadArr2 );`

Let me know if that helps you.

Comment: By the way, I just extended from the sample provided by @Pitchinnate

Answer (score -1):

A simple cast to Array will should make the the stdClassObject immediately accessible:

```
$myArray = (array)$myUnusableObject;

echo 'What have we here? '.var_export($myArray, true);
```

Comment: Why is an array more accessible than an object?

Comment: I guess I was too quick on the draw. I've had problems with working with stdClassObjects that were eliminated with a cast to Array, and I thought that's what the OP was having.